# Ember js + Rails backend, content not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I keep running into an issue with my app. When I start my local rails server and run the chrome ember inspector tool I get a few errors with obviously the fact that it seems to be just rendering a blank page. My index page works however when I use the /#/stories it renders a blank page. Previously it was working so I must've broken some code somewhere, but I can't seem to find the issue. I'm very new to ember, and somewhat new to ruby.

Error one: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. stories_route.js line: 13

```
    Sample.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
     this.store.find('story');

     return this.store.filter('story', function(story) {
        return !story.get('isNew');
     });
},
actions: {
    "delete": function(story)
        story.destroyRecord();
  }
     }
    });
```

And my second error: Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed (generated stories controller)

code for application.js:

```
    Sample.Router.map(function() {
     this.resource('stories', function() { 
  this.resource('story', { path: ':story_id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
});
this.route('new');
 });
    });
```

code for stories_controller.rb

```
    class StoriesController < ApplicationController
 def index
    render json: Story.all
 end

 def show
    render json: Story.find(params[:id])
 end
 def create
    sleep 1
    render json: Story.create(story)
 end
 def update
    render json: Story.find(params[:id]).tap { |s| s.update_attributes(story) }
 end
 def destroy
    story.find(params[:id]).destroy
    head 204
 end
   private

def story
    params[:story].permit(:title, :body)
end
   end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I made the errors unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an opening { on your delete action:

```
Sample.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('story');

    return this.store.filter('story', function(story) {
      return !story.get('isNew');
    });
  },
  actions: {
    "delete": function(story) {
      story.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sometimes I miss out silly things